# Setting Row level security with multiple columns in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, row-level-security

I am trying to create a filter for target table having country code column. I want to give access to people with logged in upn either in AdditionalOwner or OwnerEmail with countrycode

AdditionalOwner has emails separated by commas, Number of emails in additionalowner column is not fixed also it may have values from OwnerEmail column. So Please help me in giving RLS in this scenario

Please find my column structure

| CountryCode | AdditionalOwner | OwnerEmail |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AU | test1@test.com,test2@test.com | test2@test.com |

Here is the DAX I have used for Owner Email

```
[Country Code] = LOOKUPVALUE(
UserRoles[CountryCode],
UserRoles[OwnerEmail],UserPrincipalName())
```

Please help me in adding RLS for AdditionalOwner column too

Comment: This question is unclear. Are you trying to create the Table Filter Expression for a Managed Role? If so, how is the target table secured? Does the target table have CountryCode and you want to allow access to the secured table for viewers whose UPN appears in AdditionalOwner and OwnerEmail of the same country?

Comment: @DaniU Yes I am trying to create a filter. Yes, target table have country code column. Yes You are right. I want to give access to people with AdditionalOwner or OwnerEmail with countrycode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try using something like OR, IF, and CONTAINSSTRING in your managed role. I've included an example for you to test below. For transparency, I did not test this but this is where I would start to solve this.

```
OR (
 UserRoles[CountryCode] = 
    IF(    
       CONTAINSSTRING ( UserRoles[AdditionalOwner], UserPrincipalName() )
      , UserRoles[CountryCode], BLANK() )
 , UserRoles[CountryCode] = LOOKUPVALUE(
 UserRoles[CountryCode],
 UserRoles[OwnerEmail], UserPrincipalName())
)
```